# Can we get the area where ISP serving the specific ip address?

Tags: security, networking, ip-address

I got mail from snapchat that my account is logged in and they also sent some data about who logged into my account like IP address(49.206.223.160). I AM not the one who logged into my account then I got to know that someone has hacked the account. The only clue with which I was left is IP address which I am sure is that the attacker is not using any VPN. When I checked about the IP address data in https://whatismyipaddress.com/ it shows attacker is using ACT fibernet(ISP).

Now can I know about the information like area where this IP address is served by ISP.

Comment: What information are you looking to get, do you want their clothes, their boots, and their motorcycle?

Answer (score 0):

Such tools actually exist. I'm familiar with [MaxMind](https://www.maxmind.com/en/home), which is commercial.

They apparently have a [free demo](https://www.maxmind.com/en/geoip-demo). I fed the IP `49.206.222.39` and got:

```
Country Code: IN
Location: Hyderabad, Telangana, India, Asia
Network: 49.206.220.0/22
Postal Code: 500001
Approximate Coordinates: 17.3846, 78.4574
Accuracy Radius (km): 1
ISP: ACT Fibernet
Organization: ACT Fibernet
Domain: actcorp.in
Metro Code: (empty)
```